# Fail to build under circle-ci / gradle / lombok -- decorated class LombokPlugin / FindBugExtension

Tags: gradle, lombok, circleci, findbugs, gradle-plugin

I have some code that built last week on both my desktop and `Circle-CI`, but today it built only on my desktop but not on `Circle-CI`.  The error message was

```
* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'io.freefair.lombok', version: '4.1.2']
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'io.freefair.lombok']
   > Could not create plugin of type 'LombokPlugin'.
      > Could not generate a decorated class for class io.freefair.gradle.plugins.lombok.LombokPlugin.
         > org/gradle/api/plugins/quality/FindBugsExtension
```

Does this message ring a bell with someone?  (By the way, I also tried upgrading `io.freefair.lombok` to `4.1.3` but that didn't help)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution -- switch to use gradle wrapper (instead of the gradle deployed on `CircleCI`), and also make the wrapper executable.

To do the former, edit the file `config.yml` used by `CircleCI`

To do the latter, use the following `git` command:

```
$ git update-index --chmod=+x ./gradlew
```

By the way, in the error message on `CircleCI`, it mentioned `Gradle 7.0` that got me thinking that may be there was a recent version upgrade on the platform, and hence the idea of the fix.